# Knockout Radio Buttons must not be initially selected but are mapped to boolean

Tags: knockout.js

```
function SchemeViewModel(data) {
var self = this;

ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
}
```

I have the above view model which will be used on a page that is either in edit mode, in which case the model coming from the server will have boolean values that map to checkboxes or in initial mode, which will get the same object with same booleans.

A typical checkbox looks like this

```
  <input type="radio" name="mygroup1" value="Off" data-bind="radioOnOffBoolean: IsBasicPayment" />
```

My problem is that for the new application, I need the checkboxes to be unchecked, ie neither true or flase, but always map to false even in the observable is not set.

I am using the following binding handler.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.radioOnOffBoolean = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var value = valueAccessor();
    var newValueAccessor = function () {
        return ko.dependentObservable({
            read: value,
            write: function (newValue) {
                value(newValue === "On");
            }
        });
    };

    ko.bindingHandlers.checked.init(element, newValueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor);
},
update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    var newValueAccessor = function () {
        return value ? "On" : "Off";
    }
    ko.bindingHandlers.checked.update(element, newValueAccessor);
}
```

};

Comment: Radio buttons and check boxes work differently - you should edit your question to be clear which you're working with.

Comment: If you want it to be tri-state, a checkbox will not allow that. You would have to either use 3 radio buttons or a drop down with 3 options [No Value],[True],[False]. As @xdumaine says, the question needs clarification, as you show radiobutton and mention checkboxes and checked events.

Comment: Sorry, Its radio buttons I am working with , would ideally like an option to make the radio button unselected with either a true or false, could it cope with a nullable bool ? Many Thanks